# Merging text from two different sheets

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I'm looking out on how to merge text from two different sheets in a workbook if there is a match between a certain values in these two sheets.

I have two sheets, Latency and DRG. I want to merge text from "DRG" Col E into "Latency" sheet Col P (the rows might have text already, but the text from "DRG" Col E should be merged with a semicolon.)

Example : (The code below does the matching and updates a certain text in COl O, I want to add the merging part along with this code)
If there is a match in col A of "latency" and Col B of "DRG" then the text in Col E of "DRG" should be merged into Col P (that particular row) of "Latency" sheet.

Any better way of doing this is welcomed.

```
Sub PassFailValidation()

 Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, MatchRow As Variant

With Sheets("DRG")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row '<-- find last row with data in column C
    Set Rng = .Range("C2:C" & LastRow) '<-- set range in Column C
End With

With Sheets("Latency")
    For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row) ' loop through all cells in Column B
        MatchRow = Application.Match(cl.Value, Rng, 0) ' find match with values in Colummn C as in "DRG" sheet
        If Not IsError(MatchRow) Then ' <-- successful match

            Select Case Sheets("DRG").Range("D" & MatchRow + 1).Value 'Set D as the cell whch has the value
                Case "Approved"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Pass"

                Case "Pended"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "Fail"

                 Case "In progress"
                    .Range("O" & cl.Row).Value = "In progress"
             End Select
         End If
     Next cl
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you have some test data?

Comment: I can create one and upload it any third party site if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add:

```
If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then .Range("P" & cl.row).Value = Range("P" & cl.row).Value & IIf(Not Range("P" & cl.row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value
```

as follows

```
Sub PassFailValidation()

    Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, MatchRow As Variant

    With Sheets("DRG")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row '<-- find last row with data in column C
        Set Rng = .Range("C2:C" & LastRow) '<-- set range in Column C
    End With

    With Sheets("Latency")
        For Each cl In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row) ' loop through all cells in Column B
            MatchRow = Application.Match(cl.Value, Rng, 0) ' find match with values in Colummn C as in "DRG" sheet
            If Not IsError(MatchRow) Then ' <-- successful match
                Select Case Sheets("DRG").Range("D" & MatchRow + 1).Value 'Set D as the cell whch has the value
                    Case "Approved"
                        .Range("O" & cl.row).Value = "Pass"

                    Case "Pended"
                        .Range("O" & cl.row).Value = "Fail"

                     Case "In progress"
                        .Range("O" & cl.row).Value = "In progress"
                 End Select
                If Not Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value = vbNullString Then .Range("P" & cl.row).Value = .Range("P" & cl.row).Value & IIf(Not .Range("P" & cl.row).Value = vbNullString, ";", "") & Sheets("DRG").Range("E" & MatchRow + 1).Value
             End If
         Next cl
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is brilliant!!! One more thing, the ";" gets added even in an empty cell whereas it should be added only if there is an existing text...how to change this?

Comment: A silly doubt, I'm assigning this sub to a button and when i run it though the button the merge doesn't work...but when I'm in "Latency" sheet and run it through the VBA editor the code works..How do i make the code run though the button? Should the working dir be declared as "latency" ? @user3598756

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this question will attract some great VBA coded answers.  However, it is possible to use database engine technology to solve these sort of problems.  See this for starters  https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-workbooks